# XHR forbidden in Chrome extension, despite adding the correct permissions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on a [Matlab API Search](http://code.google.com/p/developer-omniboxes-for-chrome/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmatlab) addition to my [developer omnibox extensions](http://code.google.com/p/developer-omniboxes-for-chrome/), and am running up against a weird XHR issue (wondering if perhaps something changed recently in Chrome).

When the extension attempts to fetch the API function list from http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/funcalpha.html, the XHR fails with "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I have seen this failure in the past with some of my other extensions, but usually it was the result of forgetting to declare the proper permissions in the manifest. However, my manifest includes "http://www.mathworks.com/" in the permissions list, so I don't understand why this is failing. I've seen some mention of cross-origin XHR being disallowed in content scripts, but this is a script included in a background page, not a content-script, so I'm confused as to why this is failing.

NOTE: I am using Chrome 14 (dev channel). I'm curious to know if this is something that recently broke in Chrome 14 that works fine in earlier versions of Chrome, or if I'm just doing something stupid in my code. If it is broken in Chrome 14, any suggestions of a workaround would be greatly appreciated.

Manifest:

```
{
    "name":"Matlab API Search",
    "description":"Adds support to the omnibox to search the Matlab API.",
    "background_page":"background.html",
    "icons":{"128":"icon128.png", "32":"icon32.png", "16":"icon16.png"},
    "omnibox":{"keyword":"matlab"},
    "permissions":[
        "tabs",
        "http://www.mathworks.com/"
    ],
    "version":"1.0"
}
```

XHR Call:

```
xhr("http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/funcalpha.html",
    function(url, req) {
    // ...
    },
    function(url, req) {
    // ...
    }).send(null);
```

Where the `xhr` function was defined as follows:

```
  function xhr(url, ifexists, ifnotexists, retry_interval) {
    var retry_time = retry_interval || 5;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("Fetching: " + url);
    req.open("GET", url);
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4){
            var status=req.status;
            if ((status == 200) || (status == 301) || (status == 302)) {
                ifexists(url, req);
            } else {
                ifnotexists(url, req);
                setTimeout(function() { xhr(url, ifexists, ifnotexists, retry_time + 5).send(null); }, retry_time);
            }
        }
    };
    return req;
  }
```

**NOTE**
I have also tried the following permissions:

```
http://www.mathworks.com/*
http://*.mathworks.com/*
*://www.mathworks.com/*
*://*.mathworks.com/* 
*://*
http://*/*
```

(I wouldn't want to use "All your data on all websites", anyway, but this seems to imply that it isn't an issue with the way I declared my permissions, which is why I'm incredibly confused).

**Version**
14.0.803.0 (Official Build 90483) dev

**Update**
I've filed this [Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88373), since I think this is actually a bug in Chrome. However, in the event that this does not get fixed, I would really appreciate any sort of workaround that can make this work.

Comment: Is the XHR being done from a background page or a content script? If possible, can you upload a minimal example (preferably as an unpacked extension) that exhibits this problem?

Comment: It is a background page, not a content script. You can see the full source code at the link.

Comment: Do you know what the actual http request/response looks like (possibly by using Fiddler or WireShark)?  My guess is that Chrome is including the Origin header with the http request, which makes it a Cross-Domain Request (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), which in turn is causing it to fail. Maybe Chrome extensions are going to start adhering to the same-origin policy?

Comment: Update: no, it looks like an issue with 3rd party cookies being blocked, and mathworks stupidly setting lots of cookies in the response, when there is really no reason to be using cookies at all.

Comment: I'm also having problems with cross domain requests and Chrome 14 that used to work previously, at least it worked on Chrome 12.

Answer (score 0):

Add * on to the end of your URL, it is wildcard based.

```
{
    "name":"Matlab API Search",
    "description":"Adds support to the omnibox to search the Matlab API.",
    "background_page":"background.html",
    "icons":{"128":"icon128.png", "32":"icon32.png", "16":"icon16.png"},
    "omnibox":{"keyword":"matlab"},
    "permissions":[
        "tabs",
        "http://www.mathworks.com/*"
    ],
    "version":"1.0"
}
```

See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html - some of our documentation seems to imply that it works without the *, but it shouldn't (see "bad examples").

Comment: ... also, omitting the asterisk used to work. (I have several extensions that, at least when tested with earlier versions of Chrome, worked just fine, and do not include the asterisk).